# Does the Creation Club eventually present all mods for free?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, fallout-4, creation-club

Throughout the years I tend to regularly reinstall and play Skyrim Special Edition and Fallout 4 (sometimes only to answer questions here).
I've noticed that the Creation Club offers new content for free and/or with discounts. I have the feeling this happens on a biweekly basis, and that there is often at least a single freebie available.
I am wondering if it is Bethesda's policy to rotate through every single item (excluding the 'Limited time only' ones) existing in the Creation Club and offer it for free, so that, in theory, I can end up owning every CC mod without having to pay anything (because see below).

**Has there been any information regarding the way Creation Club content is offered for free?**

---

(I've never approved of the Creation Club, and will not endorse it by spending money on it. Many of Bethesda's games have been, are, and will remain popular exactly because of their devoted modding communities, and monetizing on this by allowing only a tiny selection of the great content to be 'compatible' and turning off achievements for anyone wanting to mod their games as they see fit was and remains an ungrateful slap in the face of a big chunk of their fans. /rant)

Comment: Had asked myself the same question and claimed freebies for a few months. However, some went om repeat after a while and especially the larger ones tend to only receive reductions and no freebies.

Comment: On the very rare occasion the larger mods do go free. Ive been checking semi-regularly for about 3 years now and still haven't acquired everything (i only get them when they're free). But i can't say for certain, of course... Not sure anyone can. (and i only can vouch for fo4.)